# assign index dependant value to each index in numpy array

Tags: python, vector, numpy, scipy, loops

I want to center multi-dimensional data in a `n x m` matrix (`<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>`), let's say `X` . I defined a new array `ones(645)`, lets say `centVector` to produce the mean for every row in matrix `X`. And now I want to iterate every row in `X`, compute the mean and assign this value to the corresponding index in `centVector`. Isn't this possible in a single row in scipy/numpy? I am not used to this language and think about something like:

```
centVector = ones(645)
for key, val in X:
    centVector[key] = centVector[key] * (val.sum/val.size)
```

Afterwards I just need to subtract the mean in every Row:

```
X = X - centVector
```

How can I simplify this? 
EDIT: And besides, the above code is not actually working - for a key-value loop I need something like `enumerate(X)`. And I am not sure if `X - centVector` is returning the proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some example data:

```python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.matrix(np.arange(25).reshape((5,5)))
>>> print X
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
```

numpy conveniently has a `mean` function. By default however, it'll give you the mean over *all* the values in the array. Since you want the mean of each row, you need to specify  the `axis` of the operation:

```python
>>> np.mean(X, axis=1)
matrix([[  2.],
        [  7.],
        [ 12.],
        [ 17.],
        [ 22.]])
```

Note that `axis=1` says: find the mean *along* the columns (for each row), where 0 = rows and 1 = columns (and so on). Now, you can subtract this mean from your `X`, as you did originally.

#### Unsolicited advice

Usually, it's best to **avoid the matrix class** ([see docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935)). If you remove the `np.matrix` call from the example data, then you get a normal numpy array.

Unfortunately, in this particular case, using an array slightly complicates things because `np.mean` will return a 1D array:

```python
>>> X = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
>>> r_means = np.mean(X, axis=1)
>>> print r_means
[  2.   7.  12.  17.  22.]
```

If you try to subtract this from `X`, `r_means` gets broadcast to a row vector, instead of a column vector:

```python
>>> X - r_means
array([[ -2.,  -6., -10., -14., -18.],
       [  3.,  -1.,  -5.,  -9., -13.],
       [  8.,   4.,   0.,  -4.,  -8.],
       [ 13.,   9.,   5.,   1.,  -3.],
       [ 18.,  14.,  10.,   6.,   2.]])
```

So, you'll have to reshape the 1D array into an `N x 1` column vector:

```python
>>> X - r_means.reshape((-1, 1))
array([[-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.]])
```

The `-1` passed to `reshape` tells numpy to figure out this dimension based on the original array shape and the rest of the dimensions of the new array. Alternatively, you could have reshaped the array using `r_means[:, np.newaxis]`.